# What is the definitive relationship between settings and policies in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am trying to define the relationship between settings and policies in Teams, specifically:

- Teams admin center org-wide settings
- Teams admin center global policies
- Teams admin center custom policies
- Teams client team settings

I have come up with the following statements, but would appreciate confirmation, correction or any further insight.

1. `Org-wide settings` in the admin center override `global` and `custom` policies, however `custom` policies, when applied to a user, override `global` policies for that user.
2. `Global` or `custom` policies override default `Owner` permissions (eg the ability to upload custom apps).
3. `Global` or `custom` policies override `Team Settings` defined in the Teams client.
4. (Not sure if Team settings in the admin area, override Team settings in the client?  See images 1 and 2 below)

For reference only, below are screenshots of related areas in the `Teams admin center` and `Teams client > team settings`:

- Teams client > Team > Manage team > Settings
- Teams admin center > Teams > Manage teams > Team > Edit
- Teams admin center > Teams apps > Manage apps > Org-wide app settings
- Teams admin center > Teams apps > Permission policies > Global policy
- Teams admin center > Teams apps > Setup policies > Global policy
- Teams admin center > Org-wide settings > Guest access

**Teams client > Team > Manage team > Settings**

[image]

**Teams admin center > Teams > Manage teams > Team > Edit**

[image]

**Teams admin center > Teams apps > Manage apps > Org-wide app settings**

[image]

**Teams admin center > Teams apps > Permission policies > Global policy**

[image]

**Teams admin center > Teams apps > Setup policies > Global policy**

[image]

**Teams admin center > Org-wide settings > Guest access**

[image]

**Related Links**

These links contain *related* information, but it is dispersed amongst documents and, to my understanding , doesn't provide a memorable and succinct set of statements that would be helpful when administering Teams.

[Manage Microsoft Teams settings for your organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/enable-features-office-365)

[Assign policies to your users in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/assign-policies)

[How custom app policies and settings work together](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-custom-app-policies-and-settings#how-custom-app-policies-and-settings-work-together)

[Which policy takes precedence?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/assign-policies#which-policy-takes-precedence)

Answer (score 1):

settings you should consider user settings and Team settings.
Team settings will be differ for each team, user settings will be fixed and applied.

account settings-->admincenter-users

Team settings-->admincenter-Teams-team

org-wide settings-->admincenter-orgWideSettings

[image]

remaining all are classified fine. Global and custom policies